# dict(list(tuple)) vs {list(tuple)}?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, initialization, tuples

Why does `dict(list(tuple))` work but not `{list(tuple)}`
E.g.

```
>>> dict([('b', 456), ('a', 123)])
{'a': 123, 'b': 456}
>>> {[('b', 456), ('a', 123)]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Which part of the CPython code allows for `dict([('b', 456), ('a', 123)])`?

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't learn about this before. It's the same reason `[1]` and `list(1)` don't do the same thing.

Comment: I understand that they are different but why would one allow a type cast and the other wouldn't?

Comment: The first is passing a list of key, value tuples to the dict type, which knows how to create a dict from that structure. The second is trying to use the dict literal syntax but getting the syntax wrong. It needs to be `{k: v for k, v in something}`. It's the same reason `list('a string')` gives different results to `['a string']` - it's a different syntax.

Comment: Ah ha, now I get why I had been taught `a = set()` to initialize a set, such that it can be distinguished from how I initialized a dictionary with `a = {}` =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{}` can be used for both sets and dictionaries.  For example, `{8: 2}` is a dictionary, but `{1, 2, 3, 4}` is a set.  Since you gave no key, Python assumes that you want a set.  A set depends on having hashable items, so it complains when you give it a list.

If you want to use a literal, try a comprehension:

```
{k: v for k, v in mylist}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a PEP to explain why `dict` and `set` uses the same curly brackets operator? Is it because they're both hashable, since dictionary keys are unique and so are set elements?

Comment: @alvas: Neither dicts nor sets are hashable. The dict syntax came first, and sets used curly braces too because the syntax is unambiguous (for non-empty sets) and the notation was already standard from mathematics.

Comment: There are not so many ascii enclosing characters. Tuples, lists and sets share the same basic syntax:  `OPEN elem, ... CLOSE`. There really isn't much of a choice, right? There are just three kinds of braces in ascii.

Comment: @alvas -- I think that python just ran out of different kinds of brackets to use... There's a discussion [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/001286.html) if you care to read through it.

Comment: @MaxNoe -- Technically you might argue that there are 4 types (`<>`).  But that last one is used for relational operators -- Good luck disambiguating that in the parser :-)

Comment: @mgilson Yeah, this is why i left them out :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like with `["asdf"]` and `list("asdf")` or `str(thing)` and `"thing"`, calling the dict constructor on a thing does something completely different from surrounding it with braces.

When you construct a dict with braces, you're supposed to write out key-value pairs explicitly:

```
{'b': 456, 'a': 123}
```

When you just write `{thing}`, Python sees that you've written a single item instead of key-value pairs, and it instead tries to build a single-element set containing that `thing`. This fails, because the thing in the braces is a list and lists aren't hashable.

When you construct a dict with the `dict` constructor, you can pass in a single object used to initialize the dict. This object can either be another mapping, which will be copied into the dict, or a sequence of key-value pairs represented as tuples:

```
dict([('b', 456), ('a', 123)])
```

You cannot use colon notation:

```
dict('b': 456, 'a': 123)  # Syntax error
```

You *can* use keyword arguments, since the constructor also allows you to provide string keys as keyword arguments, a syntax that the braces notation doesn't support:

```
dict(b=456, a=123)  # Works
{b=456, a=123)  # Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is a class and when you use `dict(list(tuple))` it instantiate the class using constructor.

Looking at the documentation for [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict):

> Dictionaries can be created by placing a comma-separated list of `key: value` pairs within braces, for example: `{'jack': 4098, 'sjoerd': 4127}` or `{4098: 'jack', 4127: 'sjoerd'}`, or by the dict constructor.
>
> If no positional argument is given, an empty dictionary is created. If a positional argument is given and it is a mapping object, a dictionary is created with the same `key-value` pairs as the mapping object. Otherwise, the positional argument must be an `iterable` object. **Each item in the `iterable` must itself be an `iterable` with exactly two objects. The first object of each item becomes a key in the new dictionary, and the second object the corresponding value.** If a key occurs more than once, the last value for that key becomes the corresponding value in the new dictionary.

---

When you use `{list(tuple)}` it tries to create a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) object.

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct [`hashable`](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects.

But here you have used a list element which is a mutable container and is not hashable which leads to the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

There is a nice explanation on [Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys?](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys), and the same behavior applies to set members as well.

Answer (score 0):

`dict(list(tuple))` create a new dict use the `dict()` constructor. And here is what he does

```
def __init__(self, seq=None, **kwargs): # known special case of dict.__init__
        """
        dict() -> new empty dictionary
        dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
            (key, value) pairs
        dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
            d = {}
            for k, v in iterable:
                d[k] = v
        dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
            in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
        """
```

If you use `{list(tuple)}`, you are using **set literals**. It creates a new `set`, not `dict` For **dict literals** you need minimum a pair of two values separated by a colon. (Don't ask me why ;). This is definition of Python)

To create a `set` or a `dict`, the keys (of `dict`) or values (of `set`) must be hashable. The definition says:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
>   during its lifetime

A `list` is a mutable sequence. So `list` is unhashable. That's why you got the error message

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If you want to create a new `dict` use braces from a `list(tuple)`, you can use *dict comprehension*. (But only supported on **Python 3**)

```
{a,b for a,b in list(tuple)}
```

P/S: *dict literals* is a little more performance than `dict()`